# How to find out map tile coordinates from latitude and longitude?

Tags: mapbox

I'm using Mapbox vector tiles to gather specific data from a backend process.
In the examples, they provide a link of a Manhattan tile:

http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/examples.map-zr0njcqy/14/4823/6160.png

being the tile **z**/**x**/**y** coordinates **14**/**4823**/**6160**

I know from navigating the map that the position of latitude **40.706119** and longitude **-74.017554** is inside that tile.

I also deduct from [how map works](https://www.mapbox.com/guides/how-web-maps-work/) that working with zoom 14 the entire map is composed from 16384 x 16384 tiles being 14/0/0 the top left tile.

Yet taking the 180 degrees of latitude and 360 of longitude with the total tile cols and rows gives me 14/7464/4486 which is not the same tile. (Unless I didn't do it right?)

**The question**

How do I get the tile coordinates knowing the latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 6):

Digging in mapbox-studio source code I've found this little helper object:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-studio/blob/5ac2ead1e523b24c8b8ad8655babb66389166e87/ext/sphericalmercator.js

that can be used like this:

```
> var a = new SphericalMercator()
> a.xyz([-74.017554, 40.706119], 14)
Object { minX: 4823, minY: NaN, maxX: NaN, maxY: 6160 }
```

**14**/**4823**/**6160**

Comment: it's available now as its own separate package -> https://github.com/mapbox/sphericalmercator

Answer (score 4):

You can use the below function:

```
    def deg2num(lat_deg, lon_deg, zoom):
      lat_rad = math.radians(lat_deg)
      n = 2.0 ** zoom
      xtile = int((lon_deg + 180.0) / 360.0 * n)
      ytile = int((1.0 - math.asinh(math.tan(lat_rad)) / math.pi) / 2.0 * n)
      return (xtile, ytile)
```

Above is the python implementation. You can check [Slippy map lat/long to tile number](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Lon./lat._to_tile_numbers) for implementation details and explanation.