# Achieving equal size of square/pixel on Mapbox anywhere on the world map?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

The problem I'm facing is similar and closely related to [this issue on Github](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-unity-sdk/issues/413) but that's for Unity SDK, my question is for iOS SDK.

I want to achieve the same thing. Let me explain, basically I have pixel grid in which each pixel'd have equal size. Pixel is set to be 10m x 10m in real world. The thing I experienced is that if pixel locates towards the northern or southern part of the world, its size is stretched like the following.

[image]

*Click for larger resolution*

But when such pixel locates along the equator line, or simply along the middle part of the world. It looks ok like following

[image]

*Click for larger resolution*

There's no problem about rendering stuff, or positioning on Mapbox. The thing is I want every pixel to be square visually.

I've read along on the issue I linked above. It relates to [mercator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) and the world is not flat thus makes this visual happens. It looks stretched along the northern and southern part of world map. As well, I found out that there's no equal functionalities as presented in Unity SDK for this particular problem on iOS SDK, so I'm not sure which approach I should go on to solve this solution.

How can I achieve equal size of pixel on the gridline on mapbox using Mapbox iOS SDK? Is there already solutions provided in the SDK?

**FYI**.

- My requirement also needs real distance as shown on the map. I'm not sure it'd affect the solution as presented in the link I linked above.
- I use Mapbox iOS SDK 3.7.6
- My initial approach is straightforward as I fix the size of pixel to be 10m x 10m, then calculate its corresponding latitude and longitude value. Use those values to position them in Mapbox treating entire world map as a tilemap. Anyway I didn't take into account mercator in calculation, so this might be the case, if so then how to do just that? Only thing from my checking as available in iOS SDK is `MGLMapView`'s `metersPerPoint(atLatitude:)`. No tile ID system, or [Conversions.cs](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-unity-sdk/blob/develop/sdkproject/Assets/Mapbox/Unity/Utilities/Conversions.cs) as seen on Unity SDK. So i'm not sure on how to go on and solve this problem.

**Update**
I managed to solve it and made it work!
I'll come back and post the solution.

Comment: Lines of longitude are not parallel so you can’t use the same longitude value at the top and bottom of the shape if you want it to be a square. How do you intend to handle wrapping your flat tiles at the poles?

Comment: @Magnas To be honest, I didn't take that into account from start, thus I have no idea how can I handle that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to port [sphericalmercator.js](https://github.com/mapbox/sphericalmercator/blob/master/sphericalmercator.js) to swift, then use it in code. I use a fixed zoom level of level 22 as its visual look is closest to what I need and also before. I went with the approach to at least have it looks visually equal not necessary its physical size.

> Thanks to a hint in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29221563/571227) on how to use sphericalmercator.js.

Anyway from my testing with it, tile size as set when you creating an instance using `SphericalMercator` seems not to be in effect no matter what value I set. Only zoom level will determine number of tiles across the world map for you. Note that upper-left corner is origin which is 0,0 tile index. Lower zoom level value will generate large tile size, but higher value will generate smaller tile size.

You can take a look as [SphericalMercator-swift](https://github.com/abzico/sphericalmercator-swift); the code I ported from origin JS implementation as linked above along with how to use it to get tile index, or bounding box of longitude/latitude in swift code in order to do rendering stuff on top of Mapbox.